# use AudioUnit of kAudioUnitType_FormatConverter type to resample LinearPCM data from FFmpeg

Tags: ios, audio, ffmpeg

i'm trying to play audio use AudioUnit on iOS.Because the default sample rate is 44100 and i have several audio stream of different sample rate, such as 32000,48000 etc, so i tried to set preferredSampleRate and preferredIOBufferDuration of AVAudioSession according to the audio stream.

But i found it difficult to get a proper preferredIOBufferDuration according to the preferredSampleRate, it seemed that preferredIOBufferDuration must be set differently according to the preferredSampleRate, or there may be noise.

So now i'm trying to resample all kinds of audio stream to the default hardware sample rate(44100Hz) use AudioUnit of kAudioUnitType_FormatConverter.

I use AUGraph with FormatConverter unit and remoteIO unit to do this.And now it seems i set the kAudioUnitProperty_SampleRate for kAudioUnitScope_Output successfully(the kAudioUnitProperty_SampleRate property read back is indeed 44100.But there also is noise when the input audio stream is not 44100, while it sounds normal when the input audio stream is originally 44100 Hz. Everything seems the same as i didn't use FormatConverter and directly stream data to remoteIO Unit(44100 is OK, while others not).

I wonder where is my problem.Does it not do the resampling at all, or is the output data wrong? Does anyone have experience of FormatConverter AudioUnit? Any help would be appreciated.

**My AUGraph:**

```
AUGraphConnectNodeInput(_processingGraph, converterNode, 0, remoteIONode, 0);
```

**Converter unit:**  (input format is AV_SAMPLE_FMT_FLTP from FFMpeg)

```
UInt32 bytesPerFrame = bitsPerChannel / 8;
UInt32 bytesPerPacket = bytesPerFrame * 1;

AudioStreamBasicDescription streamDescription = {
    .mSampleRate    = spec->sample_rate,
    .mFormatID      = kAudioFormatLinearPCM,
    .mFormatFlags   = formatFlags,
    .mChannelsPerFrame  = spec->channels,
    .mFramesPerPacket   = 1,
    .mBitsPerChannel    = bitsPerChannel,
    .mBytesPerFrame = bytesPerFrame,
    .mBytesPerPacket = bytesPerPacket
};

status = AudioUnitSetProperty(converterUnit, kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat, kAudioUnitScope_Input, 0, &streamDescription, sizeof(streamDescription));
if (status != noErr) {
    NSLog(@"AudioUnit: failed to set stream format (%d)", (int)status);
}

/* input callback */
AURenderCallbackStruct renderCallback;
renderCallback.inputProc = performRender;
renderCallback.inputProcRefCon = (__bridge void *)self;

AUGraphSetNodeInputCallback(_processingGraph, converterNode, 0, &renderCallback);
```

**Converter unit output sample rate:**

```
Float64 sampleRate = 44100.0;
AudioUnitSetProperty(converterUnit, kAudioUnitProperty_SampleRate, kAudioUnitScope_Output, 0, &sampleRate, sizeof(sampleRate));
```

i also tried

```
AudioStreamBasicDescription outStreamDescription = {
    .mSampleRate    = 44100.0,
    .mFormatID      = kAudioFormatLinearPCM,
    .mFormatFlags   = formatFlags,
    .mChannelsPerFrame  = spec->channels,
    .mFramesPerPacket   = 1,
    .mBitsPerChannel    = bitsPerChannel,
    .mBytesPerFrame = bytesPerFrame,
    .mBytesPerPacket = bytesPerPacket
};
status = AudioUnitSetProperty(converterUnit, kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat, kAudioUnitScope_Output, 0, &outStreamDescription, sizeof(outStreamDescription));
```

but seemed no difference.